# SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery

I have three tables as below:

Video Table
id   name
1    hello
2    world
3    new

Tag table

```
id   name
1    tag1
2    tag2
3    tag3
```

videoTag table

```
videoId    tagId
1          1
2          1
1          2
2          3
```

What i want is:

```
name       tags
hello      tag1, tag2
world      tag1, tag3
```

So, i have written the following query.

```
select
        string_agg(name, ', ')
    from
        tag t
    join "videoTag" vt on
        vt."tagId" = t."id"
    group by
        vt."videoId"
    order by
        vt."videoId"
```

This gives the following result

```
tags
tag1, tag2
tag1, tag3
```

I have the full query as:

```
with videoDetails("name",
"tags") as (
select
    v."name" as "name",
    (
    select
        string_agg(name, ', ')
    from
        tag t
    join "videoTag" vt on
        vt."tagId" = t."id"
    group by
        vt."videoId"
    order by
        vt."videoId" 
) as " tag"
from
    video v
join "videoTag" vt on
    vt."videoId" = v.id
join tag t on
    t.id = vt."tagId"
order by
    vt."videoId" 
    )
select
    *
from
    videoDetails;
```

So, I am getting the following error:
SQL Error [21000]: ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression

Comment: It's the GROUP BY subquery which is the problem. What is it supposed to do? Shouldn't it be joined instead, or be correlated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sub select is not needed (and will return more than one row, hence the error). I think you can simplify like this:

```
select
    v."name" as "name",
    string_agg(t."name", ', ' order by vt."videoId") as "tags"
from
    video v
join "videoTag" vt on
    vt."videoId" = v.id
join tag t on
    t.id = vt."tagId"
group by v."name";
```